# jquery .css() problem ...help please

Tags: jquery, css

I have   a such code  just entering start part for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Dynamically size wrapper div based on image dimensions
    $("#tag-wrapper").css({width: $("#show_img").outerWidth(), height: $("#show_img").outerHeight()});

    //Append #tag-target content and #tag-input content
    $("#tag-wrapper").append('<div id="tag-target"></div><div id="tag-input"></div>');
```

Idea is that the css properties should immediately take place when the page is loaded. But...
When I enter first time to the page, it doesnt work, when I refresh the page it works like it should. Any Idea how I can fix that?

Comment: you don't need to use jquery for this, can be done in css

Comment: Perhaps the jquery code runs before the images are loaded, so the browser doesn't know what their size is yet.

Comment: antpaw, I can't use css directlt as the outer width and outer height are not known beforehand. This is a small tagging of photos.So you never know beforehand which size of foto is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if `show_img` has a width and height set.
I believe the reason why it is not working for you is because $(document).ready is called when the DOM is loaded and before the page contents. So at that point in time `show_img` has not been loaded yet, so it can not get the width and height unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: I cant make fixed the width and heigh of the image, as the images are very different.  There can be a limit on maximums but they are notfixed I will try first answer now

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have got with php the image size and set it up dinamically. So now it's working

Answer (score 1):

The images are probably not loaded when you try to take the width and height, so you must bind a function to the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) of the document, which will ensure that all images are loaded before executing:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('#tag-wrapper').css({
        width: $('#show_img').outerWidth(),
        height: $('#show_img').outerHeight()
    }).append('<div id="tag-target"></div><div id="tag-input"></div>');
});
```

Comment: This will fail if the image is already loaded by document-ready, which is very likely for a second page load. You could instead bind to `load` on document, which fires when the document *including all images* has loaded.

Comment: Anyway thank you Tatu... I have just checked your web-site.. The CSS plugin for icons are great...